# vue-test-utils how to test component state

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

If I have a the following Component state.

```
data () {
  return {
    tasks: [
              { title: "Task 1", complete: false },
              { title: "Task 2", complete: true }
           ]
  }
}
```

How would I check that `tasks[1].complete === true` using Jest?

Here is my current test. I want to check that when trigger("click") event occurs on a checkbox, that the state is changed.

```
it("Marks a task complete when I click the task checkbox", async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(ToDoList)
    const taskInput = wrapper.find("[data-unit='taskInput']")
    await taskInput.setValue("Buy Milk")
    await taskInput.trigger("keyup.enter")
    await wrapper.find("[data-unit='task-checkbox-0']").trigger("click")
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

So I found the answer for anyone else struggling with this simple task, well simple when you know how :-)

```
wrapper.vm.$data.tasks[0].complete
```